# How to implement both fmt.Stringer and error interface on a type?

Tags: go

As with [fmt.Stringer](https://tour.golang.org/methods/17), the `fmt` package looks for the [error interface](https://tour.golang.org/methods/19) when printing values. In case if a [type](https://play.golang.org/p/I-a5AbNl6k) satisfies both interfaces, `fmt` only on look for `error` not `Stringer`. Why? How I could implement both `Stringer` and `error` on a type?

Comment: I don't know the reason why it is implemented like this but it seems that they are checking `error` before `Stringer` in `fmt.Println()`: https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go#L576

Comment: @ymonad exactly, it means no body could implement both interfaces at a time :)

Comment: @hackingNerd "it means no body could implement both interfaces at a time" this is plain wrong. Of course you can implement both interfaces. It's just that fmt.Printf chose to use `Error` first. But your type still implements both interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a universal solution, but in certain situations one can use pointer vs non-pointer receivers to do the trick: https://play.golang.org/p/DY4Cq4efsT